# Upload multiple files using http POST

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ftp, http-post

I am having a problem uploading files with FTP from my iPhone app.

I am sending an `HTTP POST` request to my webservice with all the necessary parameters. I am sending two files, one is an image, and the second is audio. The image is being uploaded, but the audio isn't.
When I trace my web service it only shows the image field as an uploaded file. It's not showing that the audio is also there.

My code is:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:ADD_LEAD_API_URL];

NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];



// change type to POST (default is GET)
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


// just some random text that will never occur in the body
NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";

// header value
NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

// set header
[postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// create data
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];



[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userId\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[appDelegate.objCurrentUser.userId dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];     


// message part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"firstName\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[firstName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

/*** My rest of string parameters are successfully added to request ***/


// media part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageUrl\"; filename=\"dummy.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // get the image data from main bundle directly into NSData object

UIImage *img= leadImage;
NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,90);

[postBody appendData:imageData];

// Image is being uploaded

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"recordSoundUrl\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", self.recordingPath] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[appDelegate.documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.recordingPath]];
[postBody appendData:soundData];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// final boundary
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// add body to post
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

// Asynch request
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

If I don't upload the image, then it takes the audio. So I am able to send only one file with the request. 
Please help me and tell me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kapil, I am facing same issue. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: What are you doing? Are you trying to upload multiple files using the way I had done? If so than after adding the image data with line: `[postBody appendData:imageData];` replace: `[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` with `[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`... Hope this helps

Comment: let me know if this not works.. I am always here to help

Comment: Kapil I tried your solution but it is not working for me, so I am going with ASIHTTPRequest. Thanx anyway.

Comment: Hi, I was using this approach to post on `facebook`. This works ok for single photo. But I want to upload number of photos in single shot, this approach will only upload one image even if I have appended 2-3 images. Is there a better way of multiple upload on facebook for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)'s `ASINetworkQueue` to send multiple files.

**UPDATE:** As per comment below, ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained. Use caution with this framework. Other options are [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: Yes this is also a good option but I am not in condition of changing my whole code.. Its done with my same code by adding `"\r\n"` after adding image data. Thanks any way

Comment: Note that ASIHTTPRequest has been deprecated between the time this was posted and now. Anyone reading this should use an appropriate amount of caution.

Answer (score 7):

It is rather simple. Just form multipart body. Suppose you have files to upload and regular params in the 'params' dictionary:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:54.0];

NSMutableData* body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString* boundary = [NSString randomStringWithLength:64];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *boundaryData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
   [body appendData:boundaryData];
    // I use special simple class to distinguish file params
   if( [obj isKindOfClass:[FileUpload class]] ) {
        // File upload
        [body appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key, [obj localName]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData: [obj loadData]]; // It just return NSData with loaded file in it
        [body appendData: [@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    else {
        // Regular param
        [body appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@\r\n", key, obj] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
    }
}];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Now you can just dispatch it in any way:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queueOfYourChoice
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *rdata, NSError *error)
```

FileUpload class is fairly trivial: it constructs from an url/filename, provides this name as a method and loads the binary content into NSData*. I don't list it for clarity, but if need, I'll add.

Comment: what is params in this sir ?

Comment: It is a dictionary with your request's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you may have a problem in setting boundary.

Use this as boundary

```
NSString boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
```

and use this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

instead of this

```
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: This almost a year old post. If you see comments on my own question I already mentioned how I solved my problem and that is same as your answer. I already fixed this issue using the same way you told (you can see my comment). Thanks anyway for trying to help me..

Comment: You should accept the most correct answer; you should be able to move your accepted answer.