# Objective C send multiple files on HTTP post

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post

Im kinda stuck right now. First of all, I'm kinda new to ios & objective-c and I'm trying to implement a feature where I need to send multiple pdf files to one email, without using the mailpickercontroller, but instead use the NSURLConnection. As of right now, this code can send a mail to each of these pdf files, which is very bad if someone plans to send 100 pdfs on their emails

```
NSString *defaultEmail = [config objectForKey:@"DEFAULT_EMAIL"];

NSArray *badgeDataLists = [self getBadgeDatas]; //list of nsdata from the pdf file

if ([NSURLConnection instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(originalRequest)] &&  defaultEmail && ![defaultEmail isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSString * email = defaultEmail;
    NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app.receptionsignin.com/mail_notification.php?key=k6j3h5u6nvh3i5jsl60ao5uqjgmso4u1&type=badge&email=%@&for=%@", email, @"All Here to See people", nil];

    for (NSData *badgeData in badgeDataLists){

        NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
        [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

         [req setHTTPBody:badgeData];
         [req addValue: @"application/pdf" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
         [req addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", badgeData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        NSLog(@"Content %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[req HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:nil completionHandler:nil];

    }                

}
```

I have tried following this links [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420453/objective-c-post-request-not-sending-data), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042360/nsdata-and-uploading-images-via-post-in-ios), and [that](http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html), where basically it involves this 'boundary' and 'multiple/form-data'. I did follow these tips and I was able to receive the mail, but it doesnt come with the attachment, so...yeah I need help about this

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12589499/1882632)

Comment: Are you pointing the one with the ASIHTTPRequest that's not reliable anymore or the answer after that that doesnt make sense for me? like where did the 'param' come from?

Comment: I was pointing to the one that doesn't make sense for you whatsoever. Sorry about that. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the link provided isnt very helpful for me, but I did manage to solve this problem. This is the code that fixed the problem. Note that the badgeDataLists are just NSData of pictures. Afterwards you let the script located on this 'path' to handle multiple files

> ```
>   NSString * email = defaultEmail;
>     NSString * path = @"some link";
> ```

```
    NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData* body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    int len = 64;
    //Creates a random boundary
    NSMutableString *boundary = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        [boundary appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }
    [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData *boundaryData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [body appendData:boundaryData];

    int i = 0;
    for (NSData *badgeData in badgeDataLists){

        // File upload
        [body appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"badge[]\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"badge%u.pdf",i++]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData: badgeData]; // It just return NSData with loaded file in it
        if (i != [badgeDataLists count]){
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
    }
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPBody:body];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:nil completionHandler:nil];
```